# Overriding the funcationality of home button

Tags: android, android-homebutton

In android i have been able to override the funcationality of back button very easily but for my app i need to override the home button. I am sure it can be done but how can i achieve this.

Comment: NO! you can not override android home key click event it prevented by system, only onStop method will call on home key click event.

Comment: but when press home button i want to show an alert so how can i do this.

Comment: on click of home key only onStop of activity will call, therefor displaying an alert on stop is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say but, It is not possible.Refer the link:-

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HOME`

Key code constant: Home key. This key is handled by the framework and is never delivered to applications.

Many blogs suggest to use onPause() method of activity life cycle,for the same.But it takes a lot to manage.

I will suggest to use onUserLeaveHint() method.

Comment: but when light is off then onPause is called but i don't want to do this.

Comment: ya i know. But most of the android blogs suggest to use onpause() methods. Its very difficult to manage.Can you tell what exactly you want to do on home press.

Comment: I want to display an alert when press home button and app is not gone in  background.

Comment: try using onUserLeaveHint(). Let me know if it works for you.